# Immediately invoked arrow function as a react prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arrow-functions

I have noticed an interesting issue in my React project. I have solved the issue by following the 1st approach but I wish to know the difference between the following callback approaches while passing as a  prop:

**1. Arrow function** (works fine inside `render()`)

```
    changeImage={ () => this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN') }
```

**2. Function reference** (Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)

```
    changeImage={ this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN') }
```

Comment: I think you get the things wrong: `this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN')` is a function call or invocation. `() => this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN')` is a function reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a function definition, you tell it to "perform this function on change". The important word is 'definition': You dont excecute it, you define it. It doesn't have the 'start' command:

```
changeImage={ () => {return this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN')}() }
// If you want it called instantly, you have to start it:     --^^
```

---

The second one you should read as a parameter. A more obvious example:

```
showImage={ this.shouldImageBeShown() }
```

That function will be called instantly to determine wether or not we should show the image, and returns true/false -> `showImage={true}`.

If you want to enter the functionname without it being triggered, you can remove the `()` part of the function so that it doesnt get called, only declared:

```
changeImage={ this.openImageUploadModal }
```

Comment: So the first approach is the only valid approach if I want to pass a parameter to the function and call ```setState``` inside it.

Comment: I'd call it "definition" because "function declaration" is already a well defined term referring to something like `function bar() {}` in a statement context.

Comment: Based on the small piece of example code, it's either your first, or my last example :) You only want it to 'start' when the image is changed, not instantly

Answer (score 0):

`changeImage={ this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN') }`

This means "call handleImageUploadModal immediately, and pass its return value into the changeImage prop". I'm guessing handleImageUploadModal calls setState, which means the component will rerender and this process repeats.

`changeImage={ () => this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN') }`

This means "create a function with the text `() => this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN')` and pass it into the changeImage prop". The newly created function is not called (yet), but can be called whenever the component deems it necessary.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you please add more information on when to follow which of these approaches or is there a better way to handle the same?

Comment: @SibasishMohanty: They are not really two different approaches. `changeImage` presumably expects to be passed a function. I doubt that `this.handleImageUploadModal('OPEN')` returns a function. This primarily seems to be a problem with understanding evaluation order in JavaScript (though I can understand that JSX makes it seemingly more complicated). But whenever you have something like `foo(bar())`, `bar` is *always* called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Function arguments are always evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: Even if you want to go with the second approach then you need to bind that function reference in the constructor using bind() in javascript, then it will behave similar to the arrow function i.e. it will trigger on the user action.